# Can I pay with PayPal to download elementary OS?

Tags: system

Can I pay with PayPal to download elementary OS ?

Answer (score 6):

The way to download and pay with Paypal is at the moment (October, 31, 2016):

- Download the OS typing `0` in the "Custom" section; afterwards press "Purchase elementary OS".
- Next to this you should click the "[Get Involved](https://elementary.io/en/get-involved#funding)" section located at the upper right position of your screen. Once there you will see different options to help elementary OS. After the "General Funding" section you have Paypal.

I hope elementary team will include Paypal in the Download area besides Card and Bitcoin as lots of users employ this payment method.

Comment: I did not know that we can use Paypal to "purchase" elementary. Thanks for this one.

Comment: For the Card+Bitcoin combo, they are using Stripe's API, a PayPal competitor, so I am not sure if they are technically or legally allowed to include PayPal as an option for purchasing alongside Stripe.