# Are there any other payment methods?

Tags: elementary-website, download

I was tring to donate for the download but my card dosen't support the payment method other than that bitcoin is something very new to me and i don't want to pay through bitcoin. Is there any other method of donating and downloding loki???

Answer (score 2):

You could enter "0" on the homepage to start the download, and then visit 
[Get Involved](https://elementary.io/en/get-involved#funding) to find another way to contribute. On that page, you can contribute via PayPal or Patreon, or by buying something from the store. You can also contribute to elementary via [Bountysource](https://salt.bountysource.com/teams/elementary).

See also: [Can I pay with PayPal to download elementary OS?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/8971/792)